# Need to add new options to DropDownList Via a textbox and a button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So I've been scouring the internet for a decent solution to this, but nothing I've tried has worked. Question is, I have DropDownLists (4 of them) that all look something like this: (These are all in the View)

```
Html.DropDownList("SeriesColor", new List<SelectListItem>

{

new SelectListItem {Text = "GR- Green", Value = "GR"},

new SelectListItem {Text = "BL - Blue", Value = "BL"},

new SelectListItem {Text = "LB - Light Blue", Value = "LB"},

new SelectListItem {Text = "NO - None", Value = "NO"},

new SelectListItem {Text = "OR - Orange", Value = "OR"},

new SelectListItem {Text = "PP - Purple", Value = "PP"}
```

I also have a text box and button: (Also in the View)

```
 <input id="addD4" type="text" />

 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add Default</button>
```

And what I want to do is allow the user to input a value (anything), press the button and have it added to the dropdownlist. Most of the solutions I've seen are either outdated, or are not supporting MVC/ Razor.

Comment: You will either end up using JavaScript or wrapping the input and button in a form and reload the page with the extended select list.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add them through JavaScript. You can do it like this using JQuery

First Bind Button onclick event to a JavaScript method like onclick="addNewItem()"

```
function addNewItem(){

$("#SeriesColor").append($('<option>', {
value: $('#addD4').val() ,
text: $('#addD4').val()
  });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this solution still isn't working. here's what my button code looks like now:     <div id="Add2" class=" InitiallyHidden">
                            <input id="addD2" type="text" />
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" 
                            onclick="addNewItem()">Add Default</button>
                        </div>

Comment: When I press the button, nothing happens

Comment: Add  new {id="SeriesColor"} at the end of  initialization of Html DropDownList , also make sure you have added jquery